# PHP - get current php version release date

Tags: php, version, maintainability

Is it possible in php to get server php version **release date**?

So let's say I've got php `5.3.28`.

Than something like `phpdate()` should return `11 Jul 2013`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basing on **Antony D'Andrea** link I've modified slightly `phpinfo_array` function so you can use it like `phpinfo_array("Build Date");`

I've also created phpdate($format) function that handles it.

```
function phpinfo_array($info=false){
    /* Andale!  Andale!  Yee-Hah! */
    ob_start(); 
    phpinfo(-1);

    $pi = preg_replace(
        array('#^.*<body>(.*)</body>.*$#ms', '#<h2>PHP License</h2>.*$#ms',
        '#<h1>Configuration</h1>#',  "#\r?\n#", "#</(h1|h2|h3|tr)>#", '# +<#',
        "#[ \t]+#", '#&nbsp;#', '#  +#', '# class=".*?"#', '%&#039;%',
          '#<tr>(?:.*?)" src="(?:.*?)=(.*?)" alt="PHP Logo" /></a>'
          .'<h1>PHP Version (.*?)</h1>(?:\n+?)</td></tr>#',
          '#<h1><a href="(?:.*?)\?=(.*?)">PHP Credits</a></h1>#',
          '#<tr>(?:.*?)" src="(?:.*?)=(.*?)"(?:.*?)Zend Engine (.*?),(?:.*?)</tr>#',
          "# +#", '#<tr>#', '#</tr>#'),
        array('$1', '', '', '', '</$1>' . "\n", '<', ' ', ' ', ' ', '', ' ',
          '<h2>PHP Configuration</h2>'."\n".'<tr><td>PHP Version</td><td>$2</td></tr>'.
          "\n".'<tr><td>PHP Egg</td><td>$1</td></tr>',
          '<tr><td>PHP Credits Egg</td><td>$1</td></tr>',
          '<tr><td>Zend Engine</td><td>$2</td></tr>' . "\n" .
          '<tr><td>Zend Egg</td><td>$1</td></tr>', ' ', '%S%', '%E%'),
        ob_get_clean()
    );

    $sections = explode('<h2>', strip_tags($pi, '<h2><th><td>'));

    unset($sections[0]);

    $pi = array();
    foreach($sections as $section){
        $n = substr($section, 0, strpos($section, '</h2>'));
        preg_match_all(
            '#%S%(?:<td>(.*?)</td>)?(?:<td>(.*?)</td>)?(?:<td>(.*?)</td>)?%E%#',
            $section, 
            $askapache, 
            PREG_SET_ORDER
        );

        foreach($askapache as $m)
            $pi[$m[1]]=(!isset($m[3])||$m[2]==$m[3])?$m[2]:array_slice($m,2);
    }

    if ( $info && isset( $pi[$info] ) ) return $pi[$info];
    return $pi;
}
```

And `phpdate` function then

```
function phpdate($format = "d M Y") {
    return date($format, strtotime( phpinfo_array("Build Date") ));
}
```

As I've just copied it, I have no idea what happens in this magic regex.

```
phpinfo_array("Build Date"); //returns Apr 10 2014 17:15:04
phpdate("d M Y"); //returns 10 Apr 2014
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean `Build Date`?

```
function phpdate($format="d M Y")
{
  ob_start(); phpinfo(1);
  if(preg_match('~Build Date (?:=> )?\K.*~', strip_tags(ob_get_clean()), $out))
    return date($format, strtotime($out[0]));
}

echo phpdate();
```

> 04 Mar 2013

[Test at eval.in](https://eval.in/273776) (*link expires soon*)

---

**Update**: To get the actual [release date](http://php.net/releases/) on Linux, could match [phpversion()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php) in the changelog:

```
// match phpversion() in changelog
function phpReleaseDate()
{
  $log = `zgrep '^[0-9].*PHP' /usr/share/doc/php5/changelog.gz`;
  $ver = preg_replace('/^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\K.*/', "", phpversion());
  $find = '/^(\d{2} [A-Z][a-z]{2} \d{4}), PHP ('.preg_quote($ver).')/';

  if(preg_match($find, $log, $out))
    return array('ver' => $out[2], 'date' => $out[1]);
}

print_r(phpReleaseDate());
```

> Array ( [ver] => 5.3.3 [date] => 22 Jul 2010 )

Tried this with Debian Linux.

Comment: @AdamPietrasiak I think it is the date, when PHP was compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I would use phpinfo() and get the Build Date from there.

There is a pretty good way of getting an array version of phpinfo in one of the examples [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php#87463).

Once you have that [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php#87463). Do:

```
$php_info = phpinfo_array(true);
$builddate = $php_info['PHP Configuration']['Build Date'];
```

Then I would make a feature request for it!

Answer (score 0):

You can always find a release date on a page: https://is.php.released.info

Comment: the question is asking for the release date of a given php version, not the release date of latest php version